# My instance is not booting and only shows “System setup” on the console connection

Tags: linux, grub, oracle-linux, cloud

I'm using Oracle's Free Tier with Oracle Linux as my VPS. A couple of days ago, I tried to install some apps and the system is down. When I connect to the console connection, It's something like this:

[image]

When I hit enter, I get following

```
Oracle AAVMF Version: 1.6.6.cvm
PEIM Loaded: PcdPeim.efi
PEIM Loaded: ResetSystemPei.efi
PEIM Loaded: MemoryInit.efi
***other modules and drivers loading***
Image Loaded: UsbMassStorageDxe.efi
Image Loaded: QemuFwCfgAcpiPlatform.efi
DXE Phase: Complete.
Tpm2SubmitCommand - Tcg2 - Not Found
Tpm2GetCapabilityPcrs fail!
Tpm2SubmitCommand - Tcg2 - Not Found
PCI Info:
PciBus: [00|00|00]
PciDev [1B36:0008:1AF4:1100]: [00|00|00]
PciDev [1AF4:1050:108E:1100]: [00|01|00]
PciDev [1B36:000D:1AF4:1100]: [00|02|00]
PciDev [1AF4:1048:108E:1100]: [18|00|00]
PciDev [1AF4:1041:108E:1100]: [00|06|00]
SecureBoot: Disabled
Boot Options:
   Boot0001: UEFI Misc Device  <VenHw(93E34C7E-B50E-11DF-9223-2443DFD72085,00)>
   Boot0002: UEFI ORACLE BlockVolume   <PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x5,0x7)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/Scsi(0x0,0x1)>
   Boot0003: UEFI PXEv4 (MAC:0200170093F8)  <PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x6,0x0)/MAC(0200170093F8,0x1)/IPv4(0.0.0.0)>
   Boot0004: EFI Internal Shell  <Fv(64074AFE-340A-4BE6-94BA-91B5B4D0F71E)/FvFile(7C04A583-9E3E-4F1C-AD65-E05268D0B4D1)>
BootNext: 
Failed to Load Boot0001 "UEFI Misc Device" from VenHw(93E34C7E-B50E-11DF-9223-2443DFD72085,00): Not Found
Loading Boot0002 "UEFI ORACLE BlockVolume " from PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x5,0x7)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/Scsi(0x0,0x1)
Starting Boot0002 "UEFI ORACLE BlockVolume " from PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x5,0x7)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/Scsi(0x0,0x1)
Use the ^ and v keys to change the selection.                       

      Press 'e' to edit the selected item, or 'c' for a command prompt.          System setup                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  The selected entry will be started automatically in 5s.                        The selected entry will be started automatically in 4s.                        The selected entry will be started automatically in 3s.                        The selected entry will be started automatically in 2s.                        The selected entry will be started automatically in 1s.                        The selected entry will be started automatically in 0s.                     Oracle AAVMF Version: 1.6.6.cvm
PEIM Loaded: PcdPeim.efi
PEIM Loaded: ResetSystemPei.efi
PEIM Loaded: MemoryInit.efi
***other modules and drivers loading***
Image Loaded: QemuFwCfgAcpiPlatform.efi
DXE Phase: Complete.
Tpm2SubmitCommand - Tcg2 - Not Found
Tpm2GetCapabilityPcrs fail!
Tpm2SubmitCommand - Tcg2 - Not Found
PCI Info:
PciBus: [00|00|00]
PciDev [1B36:0008:1AF4:1100]: [00|00|00]
PciDev [1AF4:1050:108E:1100]: [00|01|00]
PciDev [1B36:000D:1AF4:1100]: [00|02|00]
PciDev [1AF4:1048:108E:1100]: [18|00|00]
PciDev [1AF4:1041:108E:1100]: [00|06|00]
SecureBoot: Disabled
Boot Options:
   Boot0005: Oracle Linux  <HD(1,GPT,082E6D0E-4A84-47D8-A1CC-AA046E42D938,0x800,0x32000)/\EFI\redhat\shimaa64.efi>
   Boot0002: UEFI ORACLE BlockVolume   <PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x5,0x7)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/Scsi(0x0,0x1)>
   Boot0001: UEFI Misc Device  <VenHw(93E34C7E-B50E-11DF-9223-2443DFD72085,00)>
   Boot0004: EFI Internal Shell  <Fv(64074AFE-340A-4BE6-94BA-91B5B4D0F71E)/FvFile(7C04A583-9E3E-4F1C-AD65-E05268D0B4D1)>
BootNext: 
Loading Boot0000 "UiApp" from Fv(64074AFE-340A-4BE6-94BA-91B5B4D0F71E)/FvFile(462CAA21-7614-4503-836E-8AB6F4662331)
Image Loaded: UiApp.efi
Starting Boot0000 "UiApp" from Fv(64074AFE-340A-4BE6-94BA-91B5B4D0F71E)/FvFile(462CAA21-7614-4503-836E-8AB6F4662331)
```

Then this

[image]

[image]

If I click the first two options, I only see “System Setup”. When I enter System setup, the same things happens. I click c to enter grub menu, and I type boot, it says you need to load the kernel first.
What I tried: I entered EFI shell, downloaded netboot.xyz EFI using TFTP, booted into Ubuntu rescue mode. I entered Oracle Linux's shell using chroot. Reinstalled kernel, grub2 etc. But no success. I just need to get some mysql dbs, after that I will install Ubuntu.